# How can I set Primary Key Value manually in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I am Trying to set Primary Key Value Manually in Laravel 5.6 but it return 0 when record save.
Here is my code of Controller Function.

```
   $next = collect(DB::select('SELECT IFNULL(MAX(IFNULL(lvl1,0)),0)+10 AS NEXTVAL FROM coa_lvl1'))->first()->NEXTVAL;

    $lvl1_id = new CoaLvl1();
    $lvl1_id->lvl1 = $next;
    $this->lvl1->create(array_merge($request->all(),['lvl1' => $next , 'lvl1_code' => $request->get('group_id').'/'.$next]));
```

Migration For coa_lvl1:

```
    Schema::create('coa_lvl1', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->tinyInteger('group_id');
        $table->integer('lvl1')->unsigned();
        $table->tinyInteger('lvl1_code');
        $table->string('lvl1_name',300);
        $table->integer('created_by')->nullable(false);
        $table->timestamp('created_date')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
        $table->integer('last_update_by');
        $table->timestamp('last_update_date')->default(DB::raw('0 ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
        $table->string('active_flag',1)->default('1');
        $table->primary('lvl1');
        $table->foreign('group_id')
            ->references('group_id')
            ->on('coa_group')
            ->onDelete('cascade');
    });
```

And in  my Model

```
  protected $table = 'coa_lvl1';

 protected $primaryKey = 'lvl1';

public $incrementing = false;

protected $blameable  = array('created','updated');

protected $fillable = ['group_id','lvl1_code','lvl1_name','active_flag'];

  public $timestamps = false;

 public function coaGroup()
 {
   return $this->belongsTo(CoaGroup::class, 'group_id');
  }

  public function coaLvl1()
  {
   return $this->hasMany(CoaLvl2::class,'lvl1');
  }
```

$next is my PrimaryKey Value that I am trying to set

Comment: Do you have migration files? A table can only have a primary key so you might already have one existing in table before the column.

Comment: $table->tinyInteger('group_id');
            $table->integer('lvl1')->unsigned();
            $table->tinyInteger('lvl1_code');
            $table->string('lvl1_name',300);
$table->primary('lvl1');

Comment: In My Model 
protected $primaryKey = 'lvl1';

public $incrementing = false;

Comment: Please update your post and include everything inside.Kinda hardly see from comments Thanks

Comment: You're declaring `lvl1` column twice, you only need the column with `primary('lvl1')`

Comment: I have Created Column lvl1 after that I made it primary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this by adding primarykey in protected

```
   $fillable = ['lvl1','group_id','lvl1_code','lvl1_name','active_flag'];
```

I think its not right way but its working for me

Answer (score 1):

```
Schema::create('coa_lvl1', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->tinyInteger('group_id');
    $table->integer('lvl1')->primary(); //$table->integer('lvl1')->unsigned();
    $table->tinyInteger('lvl1_code');
    $table->string('lvl1_name',300);
    $table->integer('created_by')->nullable(false);
    $table->timestamp('created_date')->default(DB::raw('CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
    $table->integer('last_update_by');
    $table->timestamp('last_update_date')->default(DB::raw('0 ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'));
    $table->string('active_flag',1)->default('1');
    $table->foreign('group_id')
        ->references('group_id')
        ->on('coa_group')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

My Model is like This

```
protected $table = 'coa_lvl1';

protected $primaryKey = 'lvl1';

public $incrementing = false;

protected $blameable  = array('created','updated');

protected $fillable = ['group_id','lvl1_code','lvl1_name','active_flag'];

public $timestamps = false;

public function coaGroup()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(CoaGroup::class, 'group_id');
}

public function coaLvl1()
{
    return $this->hasMany(CoaLvl2::class,'lvl1');
}
```

Comment: Still Same Problem It save 0 in PrimaryKey

Comment: @Almani Can you show your model do you have protected $fillable = ['col1','col2',...] ?

Comment: @Almani i have roughly added the protected $fillable = []; Try again see if it work

Comment: I have done this by adding primarykey in protected $fillable = ['lvl1','group_id','lvl1_code','lvl1_name','active_flag'];
I think its not right way but its working for me